# I recieve this error when trying to import fontawesome

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

`Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module format not recognized: C:\Users\pinto\Downloads\fontawesome-free-6.1.1-desktop.zip`

this is my import and the hover over error.

`import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon; import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView;`

The import de cannot be resolved

Comment: If you examine that zip file, you’ll see that it contains no Java classes.  Also, zip files are not valid Java modules;  generally only .jar files are.

Answer (score 1):

What does this zip-file do on your module path? This will not work.

I'd also advise you to use https://kordamp.org/ikonli/ instead.

Comment: thank you, This zip-file is supposedly the fontawesome icon pack, I just want to include the icons in my program.